# Parse the resistors

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

The aim is simple: given the string of resistance values, draw the part of "electrical circuit" of those resistors. Examples follow.

1. Input: `3`. Output:

   ```
   --3--
   ```
2. Input: `1,2,3`. Output:

   ```
   --1----2----3--
   ```

Next, the resistors can be joined parallel (by 2 or 3 resistors per join), but the required depth of parallel joins is only 1.

3. Input: `1|2`. Output:

   ```
    |--1--|
   -|     |-
    |--2--|
   ```
4. Input: `1|2|3`. Output:

   ```
    |--1--|
   -|--2--|-
    |--3--|
   ```

   **Note**, that `--2--` resistor is now centered.
5. Input: `1|2,3|4|5`. Output:

   ```
    |--1--|  |--3--|
   -|     |--|--4--|-
    |--2--|  |--5--|
   ```

Combined joins:

6. Input: `1,2,3|4,5,6|7|8,9`. Output:

   ```
              |--3--|       |--6--|
   --1----2---|     |---5---|--7--|---9--
              |--4--|       |--8--|
   ```

If it would be more convenient, the input can be a two-dimensional array. I.e. the input for the last example would look like this: `[1,2,[3,4],5,[6,7,8],9]`.

Some notes:

- No other forms of (in|out)puts are allowed.
- The resistance of each resistor can vary in the range from 1 to 9. Other values, like `-`, `42` or `0` are disallowed.
- The joins like `1|2|3|4` are invalid. As already mentioned, max 3 per parallel join. Empty joins, i.e. `...,|,...` or `...,,...` are invalid.
- Oh, and this is code golf :)

Comment: Thanks for the correction, it's a fixed numbers of dashes. The separate resistors are preceded and followed by two dashes.

Comment: Can the first and third line be padded with spaces to even the length of the lines?

Comment: @Tfeld Trailing/leading spaces are allowed before/after the whole output, but not between the resistors.

Comment: Are leading/trailing empty lines allowed when there are no parallel resistors?

Comment: @Pietu Hm, let it be yes :)

Comment: Both `[1,2,[3,4],5,[6,7,8],9]` and `[[1],[2],[3,4],[5],[6,7,8],[9]]` fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Python 2, 195 bytes

```python
a=b=c=''
B=' '*5
H='--'
S=' |'+H;E=H+'| '
for x in input():
 if x>9:a+=S+`x[0]`+E;c+=S+`x[-1]`+E;b+='-|'+[B,H+`x[1]`+H][len(x)>2]+'|-'
 else:b+=H+`x`+H;a+=B;c+=B
print[b,a+'\n'+b+'\n'+c]['|'in a]
```

Takes input as:

```
[1,2,[3,4],5,[6,7,8],9]
```

Output:

```
           |--3--|       |--6--|      
--1----2---|     |---5---|--7--|---9--
           |--4--|       |--8--|
```

Comment: Save a few bytes by making `H` a function `lambda V:f'--{V}--'`?

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 64 bytes

```
ƛI⁼[h\-dpømð5*:‟W|ƛ`|--`pøm;:L2=[÷`|   `øm$W]];DvhṄ,ƛ1i;\-j,vtṄ,
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C6%9BI%E2%81%BC%5Bh%5C-dp%C3%B8m%C3%B05*%3A%E2%80%9FW%7C%C6%9B%60%7C--%60p%C3%B8m%3B%3AL2%3D%5B%C3%B7%60%7C%20%20%20%60%C3%B8m%24W%5D%5D%3BDvh%E1%B9%84%2C%C6%9B1i%3B%5C-j%2Cvt%E1%B9%84%2C&inputs=%5B1%2C%5B2%2C3%5D%5D&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>45</s> 42 bytes

```
ε€…--ÿDgið.ø.BëÁð3×ª3£À'|ì… - SδìÅ\]€.ºøJ»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AWMAnP9vc2FiaWX//8614oKs4oCmLS3Dv0RnacOwLsO4LkLDq8OBw7Azw5fCqjPCo8OAJ3zDrOKApiAtIFPOtMOsw4VcXeKCrC7CusO4SsK7//9bMSxbNyw4XSwyLFszLDQsNV0sNl0)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 149 bytes

```javascript
n=>(H=M=>n.map(e=>(T=e[M]||e[1])?` |${(G=e=>`--${e}--`)(T)}| `:'     ').join``)(0)+`
${n.map(e=>+e?G(e):`-|${e[2]?G(e[1]):'     '}|-`).join``}
`+H(2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZDNbsIwEITveQofIrEm61BC6Q@SwzG5cAo3y5IjaioQ2KhUvcR59tSuAioICbG3Wc@M1t@2/qmPq6/N4ZsZ@6G7Ne8Mz6HkC56bdF8fQHu55FospHNajCWdK@LiBgruXxRjcaNbxhSFJW0dUbMBCTOg6dZujPL7J5qoKG7ObYmeF6DpTDFfo0UmgwzFp2jrfF0fbyOVlJDRbmXN0e50urOfsAYxxgzFBJ8lTlG84Cu@SXyXlEb/fZeqT03uuoJN/rXjVAb3aEjAYMX7@/Dq63ifVnGiU5258Lx8AE11CwoZjrpf)

No need to overcomplicate things, just keep it simple

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 132 bytes

```hs
foldr(zipWith(:))e.(>>=g)
a=" - "
b="|||"
s%c=[a,b,c,c,s,c,c,b,a]
g[x]=[a,a,' ':x:" ",a,a]
g[x,y]=[x,' ',y]%"- -"
g z=z%"---"
e=[]:e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYnNCoJAFEb38xSXS6LCTNB/CeMT1KpFC3MxmqOS2qAGJj570634@A4HTqG6e1ZVVsur1Y/q1npjaS5lX3iB72dzLwxl7jMlEQQgSyRO04Ssc1IZKZ7wlNb9mHAVszwa4m9Q3AU3GAIEJP8H/qI0fAOZgwIEshxGOZIL8kxGcZDZWpUNSKiVOYF59ue@PTYwAw0RLpDjkr5aEzb07W5PPGBs36muVN5ZkRrzAQ)

Takes input as a `[[Char]]` and outputs a list of lines.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.5](http://julialang.org/), 129 bytes

```julia
s=" "^5
+x="--$x--"
!x=map(*,[" |","-|"," |"],x,["| ","|-","| "])
-x=[[s,.+x,s],![+x[1],s,+x[(l=end;)]],!.+x][l]
~x=map(*,.-x...)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVBBTsMwELznFVvDwSZrpyEN0KJw4Ij4gWUkt00bV4kT1Q4yUtSvh6SoEpfZ2Rnt7GpPfW10GsZGd/SAQQjBoIB37UrxJ0kj001jrGn6htalPfpK0MCYgkN7BgPGQlDXsTvwLTTa7ypIRR7Dtqz0t2n7M9DK@85tkuRofNVvxa5tko958ae2x@Q0s8Q415cuybJstWSjKwiQrzyKQ0E4vw@ck2gRivmkB5QEBoKEzzAxhWGSBpi6gc8ARLGIh0JKhyIO6BQuZBxkqtDhVGldlHb/ytSkT76StYout3DBr08YLzLFR5QZrhTmKJ/wGV8UrhUMb7A3rqv1T9SdjfW1pSy60OVmzf554y8)

output is a list of lines